# template-determined class as return-type of a template function, that uses template template parameters

Tags: c++, templates, template-templates

I have `std::vector<double>` , and my type `Array`-like.
Also, there are a lot of numbers in `std::vector<double> source`, and I would like to make this code work in the way:
`std::cout << toHisto(source, /* other parameters like min, max, stacks */);`
And I guessed that would be good, if the function `toHisto` worked with other containers, such as with my `Array`. Thou, I tried to do this, and have a problem in return type of template function `Error C3200  'Container<double,std::allocator<double>>': invalid template argument for template parameter 'Container', expected a class template`

If you have any proposals, I would be glad to hear.

Code here:

````
template<template <class T, class Allocator = std::allocator<T>> class Container>
class MyClassForOstream {
public:
    Container<double> &res;
    double min;
    double max;
    MyClassForOstream(Container<double> r, double min_, double max_) : res(r), min(min_), max(max_) {}
    friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& out, MyClassForOstream const& s) {
        /* sth like for(i in s)"out << s[i]" , and some format stuff from <iomanip>*/
        return out;
    }
};

template<template <class T, class Allocator = std::allocator<T>> class Container>
// Error here at specifing params for  MyClassForOstream < /* here */>
MyClassForOstream<Container<double>> toHisto(Container<double> const& gen, double min, double max, size_t stocks) { // class template must have: operator[], .size(), ctor(size)
    
    Container<size_t> tmp(stocks);
    for (size_t i = 0; i != stocks; ++i) {
        tmp[i] = 0;
    }
    for (size_t i = 0; i != gen.size(); ++i) {
        ++tmp[static_cast<size_t>(((min + gen[i]/(max+min))*((max-min)*stocks)))];
    }  
    Container<double> res(stocks);
    for (size_t i = 0; i != res.size(); ++i) {
        res[i] = 0;
    }
    for (size_t i = 0; i != res.size(); ++i) {
        res[i] = static_cast<double>(tmp[i])/gen.size();
    }

    
   return MyClassForOstream<Container<double>> (res, min, max ); // also error here
}```
````

Comment: You could make `toHisto` just take iterators as input. That's the way most of the standard library works.

Comment: Make it `template<template <typename ... Args> class Container> ...`, so you can take a container with any number of arguments, and not require exactly two.